# Label certain features of the layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, labeling

I have a world country map with a field of showing dengue data in some countries.

I want to label only those country with dengue data in the map. I do not know how to do that in ArcGIS. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

Go to Layer Properties -> Labels and do the following as you can see in the image below:

[image]

(1) Change the Method to "Define classes of features and label each cclass differently"

(2) Use "SQL Query" to define the field that has dengue info.

Comment: To build your SQL Query, choose the column that you want to use to select the features for display. (It will appear within " " in the box below). If you want to choose one categorical value, click on the box with the equal sign (or type it). Click on the button "Get unique values" to show the options/values for the column. Then select one of those (or type it in with correction format, text seems to require a ' before and after).